# Program to create pictures for applications

Tags: software-recommendation, 3d

I am not very good when it comes to creating images. So, I decided that I wanted to learn. The reason is, I am creating a chat program/game where I want to be able to create some pictures. I was wondering what type of program you guys think is best to use when creating new pictures. What I am looking for is a program to create pictures like these:

[image: scene]

[image: icon thing]

Also since I'm kind of new it, it would be nice if the program wasn't too advanced

Comment: This question is **exceptionally** broad. There are dozens if not hundreds of image editors out there ranging from Adobe Photoshop/Illustrator to small freeware editors. What have you tried?

Comment: I'd say software like AutoDesk Maya and others since it's in 3D...

Comment: Your examples don't really make sense - you say "images like these" and then provide two quite bizarre images that have nothing to do with one another.

Comment: @JackM They do regarding the angle (seen from above).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first image, the 3d freeware program [Blender](http://www.blender.org/) could be appropriate - but it is rather complex, especially for a beginner; however, the image you posted is equally not beginner level.

For the icon like character of your second image, the freeware program [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/) could fit you.

Both recommendations are free, so you don't have to invest money - **you will have to invest a lot of time** though to get the results you are looking for, considering you claim to have little to no experience with image creation software.

Comment: how hard is the first picture to create? (creating pictures like that one)

Comment: @MarcRasmussen 3D modelling has quite a learning curve on it to begin with, and while the geometry of the objects in that scene is very simple, it would still likely be a lot of work for a beginner. The most complex thing I've modelled is a glass of water, so I'm very much a beginner, and personally I'd say that I could do something like that image, but I wouldn't look forward to it. Hours of work.