# Outdoor light simulation program

Tags: software-recommendation, 3d, shadows

For a project I  want to model a outdoor light scene. Therefore I'm looking for an easy way to produce basic 3D objects and simulate sunlight over the day. 
Thus program should be able to:

- Create simple 3D models
- Change the position of the sun
- In the best case the program can also return an array of the light 
  values the different pixels

I have something in mind like [this](https://www.dial.de/en/software/dialux/features) but with an option for dynamic sunlight.

Comment: Those 3D renders you linked to are not simple at all, but highly complex - probably using something like Maya, Cinema 4D or Blender. The last one is free.  All have a huge learning curve.

Comment: What does this have to doe with graphic design?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Program to create pictures for applications](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13332/program-to-create-pictures-for-applications)

Answer (score 0):

Updated some years later.

Blender has some sun-date-location modules.

Take a look https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/lighting/sun_position.html

You can find some tutorials:
https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=blender+sun+position

Some other modeling software like Sketchup, commonly used to make architecture design also has the option:

https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=sketchup+sun+position

---

Old answer:

But give it a try to http://www.kerkythea.net

It is a stand-alone render engine, that has actually different rendering methods, for photorealistic images, but depending on how skillful is the author.

But it meets your initial requirements. You can make simple shapes. If you need more elaborate shapes you can use also Sketchup to model stuff and then export it to Kerkythea.

You can also assign a sun position by location, date, and daytime.

I did not understand this:

> an array of the light values the different pixels

That is probably a "render". In this case, you have a render method that gives the "luminosity" values, called Clay Render.

The problem would be to make an animation.

---

You can also use any 3D application like https://www.blender.org and you can animate the sun path if you know the values.

---

There are some tools to create specific types of an exterior, or landscapes, like Terragen, Vue, Bryce. Some of them have a free version, but some have different render quality. Google landscape

---

I found this application but is more suitable to analyze interior's sunlight http://www.velux.com/article/2016/daylight-visualizer

---

P.S. There is another forum for this kind of question: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/